Unable to mock Scala object
I have started working in Scala very recently. I have below code in the main method that I'll need to mock for writing test cases,
object SacSAAgentSoftwareLogParser extends SparkSessionCreation {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      secret = mapAsJavaMap(SecretConfig.apply())
      
      ...
      

Here is how the object SecretConfig is defined. It reads configs from HC Vault.
object SecretConfig {

  def apply(): collection.Map[String, String] = {
  
  ...

In the test case, I am trying to mock the SecretConfig.apply() so that it does not make a real-time call while executing the same -
class SacSAAgentSoftwareLogParserTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar {

  "SacSAAgentSoftwareLogParser" should "execute the main method and process data correctly" in {
  
  val intermediateSecretMap: collection.Map[String, String] = Map( "secret1" -> "value1")
  
      withObjectMocked[SecretConfig.type] {
      when(SecretConfig.apply()).thenReturn(intermediateSecretMap)
    }

    ...

SacSAAgentSoftwareLogParser.main(Array.empty)
    ...

However, the mocking does not really work while running the test case. Instead, it goes on to call the SecretConfig.apply() in real time. Definitely I'm doing some mistakes here, just not able to figure out what they are. There might be some gap in my understandings as well.

Mocking objects is usually sign of a bad design since they're supposed to be singletons. You might want to use regular classes and dependency injection as a replacement.

I understand that. However, changing this at design level is beyond my control actually.

Did you add the src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker file as described in https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala?tab=readme-ov-file#mocking-scala-object

Yes, I have already added mock-maker-inline in that, as suggested there.
